# Azure VM unable to log

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm using Microsoft Azure VM and have reset the Administrator password using:

> `Computer Management - > User and Groups - > Right click and Reset`

But once I try to RDP  as Administrator,the new password didn't work out.
I tried to reset the password using powershell ISE with below explanation .
[Resetting Admin Passwords on Microsoft Azure VM’s](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/06/26/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx)

And I found that VM Agent is not installed.
How can I install the VM Agent using Powershell ISE and then reset Admin password ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to connect via RDP to be able to install the agent via executing a msi in the VM. You can download the msi for agent on Microsoft site.

The to let VM know that agent is installed you can execute below cmdlets via Azure PowerShell:

```
    $vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName [Name]
    $vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent = $true
    Update-AzureVM –VM $vm.VM -ServiceName
```

Answer (score 0):

If the agent is not installed this usually means that the VM image was not properly preped / generalized for Azure. I have had this situation(it was quite weird as I will use an image to deploy few VMs then about a week later new VM provisioning will start to fail stating agent was missing. When I called support and worked with them it got traced to bad provision process on my end)